# SQL - How can I use UNION to join three INNER JOIN results into a single results table?

Tags: mysql, sql

For the table:

```
assistants_rating(
id INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
assistant_id INT(11),
rating INT(1)
)
```

And another table of assistants which contains a name. My query goes as follows:

```
(SELECT assistants.name AS assist_name , count(rating) AS OneStar FROM assistants_rating
INNER JOIN assistants on assistants.assistant_id = assistants_rating.assistant_id WHERE rating = 1)

UNION

(SELECT assistants.name AS assist_name , count(rating) AS TwoStar FROM assistants_rating
INNER JOIN assistants on assistants.assistant_id = assistants_rating.assistant_id WHERE rating = 2)

UNION

(SELECT assistants.name AS assist_name , count(rating) AS ThreeStar FROM assistants_rating
INNER JOIN assistants on assistants.assistant_id = assistants_rating.assistant_id WHERE rating = 3)

GROUP BY assistants.name,OneStar,TwoStar,ThreeStar;
```

Let's say I have the assistants named Bob and Sophie, the query should return:

```
assist_name   OneStar    TwoStar    ThreeStar

  Bob            9         18          52

 Sophie          15        8           61
```

But instead I'm getting a SQL syntax error, which is weird because when I do each of them alone , they work properly and that leads me to believe that my syntax is good. Not only that, but my queries with the `UNION` work if I only do `TwoStar` and `ThreeStar` together but not with `OneStar` and `TwoStar`.

I'm so confused; why doesn't this work?

Comment: [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) combines the result sets produced by two or more queries and optionally sorts the result set it generates. It doesn't `GROUP BY`. The queries you union here [are invalid SQL and return indeterminate results](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for `assistants.name`.

Comment: What would be a better way to go about fixing my issue then ? It appeared to me that the union keyword was what I needed :/

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve by that!

Comment: `assistants.name` -> `name` in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: As said in the post , I'm trying to achieve a query where a single row returns , the assistants' name , the number of one star rating he has , two stars and three stars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UNION` doesn't help here anyway. It does a different thing.

The query you need is something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 
    assistants.name AS assist_name, 
    SUM(IF(rating = 1, 1, 0)) AS OneStar,
    SUM(IF(rating = 2, 1, 0)) AS TwoStar,
    SUM(IF(rating = 3, 1, 0)) AS ThreeStar
FROM assistants_rating
    INNER JOIN assistants ON assistants.assistant_id = assistants_rating.assistant_id
GROUP BY assistants.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` instead of Union

```
SELECT assistants.name AS assist_name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OneStar,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating =2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TwoStar,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating =3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ThreeStar
FROM assistants_rating
INNER JOIN assistants on assistants.assistant_id = assistants_rating.assistant_id 
GROUP BY assistants.name
```